# Cut Video from Start Point to End Point c#

Tags: c#, windows, video

I have create code which will read video .mp4 file from server using DownloadStream.Read(buffer, 0, DownloadBlockSize) method and write it fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount) method on local directory.

It's working fine with full video download and also working fine with trim from last.

But when I trying to trim from starting point, it will not work and downloaded file is not work.

```
while (true)
{
   int readCount = DownloadData.DownloadStream.Read(buffer, 0, DownloadBlockSize);
   if (readCount == 0) break;
   fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
   fileStream.Flush();
}
```

I need to trim video from start point to specific duration and download it in local directory.

For Exp.
If video full length is 10 min.

I want to download video from 05:00 min to 08:00 minute (middle 3 minute video).

I can do it from 00:00 min to 08:00, but not from middle.

Comment: If you skip the beginning of the file/video, you usually skip the header which is needed for a working copy. To get something working you probably need to create your own header, make sure to start on something that is a "frame" and so on. I would guess it would require some good knowledge of the formats you want to support - time to google it ;)